# Set Heroku like webhook for a Telegram Bot

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

how can I set Heroku like webhook for a Telegram Bot written using [python-telegram-bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot)?
What I have to add in the code?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  set_webhook() function

```
bot.set_webhook('https://test.co/path')
```

Note! API method getUpdates doesn't work while webhook setted. So you may use

```
bot.delete_webhook()
```

to free it.